# How to Import Excel table to Lotus Notes View

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a Excel table with many customers and I like to import this to a Lotus Notes view.
I have created a form with fields with the same name as the columns in Excel, and a view with the same fields as columns. Then I try to import to this view but It results in only one form generated, WHY

Thanks

Comment: In which format is the file? At least my Notes client does not show import option for Excel.

Comment: Can you give more detail of the steps you are following?

Comment: Well I have a csv file from Excel. I have created a Lotus Notes form with fields named same as excel columns. And I have created a Lotus Notes view and named the columns same order as excel table/workbook.

Answer (score 2):

IBM Notes doesn't have built-in support to import or export directly to Excel. In the old days it was possible to mess around with exporting Excel to Lotus 123-files, and then import them to Notes. Since many years ago, Microsoft abandoned the possibility to export to 123.

If you know how to program, this can be achieved pretty easy by using for example [this LotusScript code](http://openntf.org/Projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/CodeByDate/DCD5A132F75581698625726700715FCA) from OpenNTF.org. I believe if you search the net for words like "import excel into Lotus Notes" you will get a pretty list of choices.

If you don't mind 3. party products, I happen to be the author of [Notes Import Export Library](http://www.vcode.no/web/vcode.nsf/htdocs/iel) which is an import/export library and puts the ability to import and export directly to Excel again.

Happy importing!